# Selenium :- I want to concat two div value in selenium with java. want value as (Strength+25G PLANT PROTEIN)

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

```
**Please refer below code:-**

<div class="h3">
<strong>STRENGTH</strong> div 1
</div>
 <div class="h3 tagline">
<strong>25G PLANT PROTEIN </strong> div 2
</div>
```

Selenium :- I want to concat two dave value in selenium with java. want value as (Strength+25G PLANT PROTEIN)

Comment: Is it value, not a text?

Comment: It is text that need to concat

Answer (score 0):

var attribute1Value = element.getAttribute("//div[@class="h3"]");
var attribute2Value = element.getAttribute("//div[@class="h3 tagline"]");

// Concatenate the values
var concatenatedValue = attribute1Value + "+"+ attribute2Value;